# Postgres sorted join with millions of rows, low cardinality, slow query - time to partition tables?

Tags: query-performance, join, postgresql-performance, partitioning, order-by

I have an API that is used to query for data about programs and other forms of content.

We have a few tables that I need to join on to fullfil an ad-hoc query, and I am running into trouble speeding this up. I included the indices below, it feels like we've covered a lot of the usual suspects when it comes to optimizing the queries, I may be missing some easy optimizations but I think in general we need to look into partitioning the data.

We have the following query:

```
SELECT x.content_id
 FROM program AS x
 JOIN content AS c ON c.content_id=x.content_id 
 JOIN program_titles AS pt ON pt.content_id=x.content_id 
 JOIN content_map AS cm ON cm.content_id=x.content_id 
WHERE x.rating_tags='{}' AND c.type= 3 AND pt.title ILIKE '%game%' AND cm.service_id= 81 
ORDER BY x.ts_updated DESC,x.content_id LIMIT 100;
```

With the following (simplified) tables and indices for the remaining columns:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS program (
 content_id bigint not null,
 rating_tags jsonb not null '{}'::jsonb,
 ts_updated timestamp with time zone not null DEFAULT timezone('UTC'::text, now())
);

Indexes:
    "program_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (content_id)
    "program_tag_idx" gin (rating_tags)
    "program_pagination_idx" btree (ts_updated DESC, content_id)

total rows: 55,584,745 rows
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS content (
    content_id bigint not null,
    type integer not null
);
Indexes:
    "content_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (content_id)
    "content_type_idx" btree (type)


type = 7: 1,998,433 rows
total rows: 67,651,231 rows
type has low cardinality (14 possible values)
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS content_map (
    external_id text not null,
    service_id integer not null,
    content_id bigint not null,
   ts_updated timestamp with time zone not null DEFAULT timezone('UTC'::text, now())
);
 
Indexes:
    "content_map_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (external_id, service_id)
    "content_map_content_id_idx" btree (content_id)
    "content_map_pagination_idx" btree (ts_updated DESC, external_id, service_id)
    "content_map_service_idx" btree (service_id)


service_id = 81: 4,049,917 rows
total rows: 71,514,789
service_id has low cardinality (12 possible values)
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS program_title (
   language_code varchar(3) not null,
   region_code varchar(3) not null,
   content_id bigint not null,
   title text not null,
   episode_title text not null,
   ts_updated timestamp with time zone not null DEFAULT timezone('UTC'::text, now())
);

Indexes:
   "content_title_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (content_id, language_code, region_code)
   "episode_title_trgm_idx" gin (episode_title gin_trgm_ops)
   "program_title_pagination_idx" btree (ts_updated DESC, content_id, language_code, region_code)
   "title_trgm_idx" gin (title gin_trgm_ops)

title ILIKE 'game' = 31 rows
total: 52,550,728 rows
```

```
Postgres version: PostgreSQL 10.15 (Debian 10.15-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
SHOW work_mem; '128MB'
```

What I've tried:

1. Check work_mem (already high at 128MB, query planning does not appear to show it as a problem)
2. Adding indices, including on sort pagination
3. Full text search instead of trigram index on program_titles.title

What I think I should try next:

1. The very low cardinality of a few of columns in the tables we are joining makes me think we can benefit from partitioning. My big question is how much this will slow down queries that do not use the paritioned columns. There may be other queries with no filter params, so we would basically be sorting by content.ts_update, so we would need to look at all of the partitions to satisfy this query. Presumably that means we want to also partition by ts_updated, too? Or is that the kind of thing that is dependent on your dataset and requires experimentation?
2. Add indices that cover multiple columns? I'm not sure if something like a covering index (CREATE INDEX i ON content_map(service_id) INCLUDE (content_id)) is preferred over an index on both columns ((service_id, content_id), (c.type, c.content_id), etc).
3. Since we have a large join, possibly temporary tables?

If it's easier, we can maybe ignore the ILIKE clause and program_titles table. These are ad-hoc queries, so we may not see a title filter all the time, and I don't want to rely on using high cardinality table to resolve it if we can't count on that clause always being used. I included query plans for with and without the join on program_titles.

Query plans:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT x.content_id
 FROM program AS x
 JOIN content AS c ON c.content_id=x.content_id 
 JOIN program_title AS pt ON pt.content_id=x.content_id 
 JOIN content_map AS cm ON cm.content_id=x.content_id 
 WHERE x.rating_tags='{}' AND c.type= 3 AND cm.service_id= 81 
 ORDER BY x.ts_updated DESC,x.content_id;


 Gather Merge  (cost=2274245.42..2274431.17 rows=1592 width=16) (actual time=5455.963..5465.479 rows=19 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Sort  (cost=2273245.40..2273247.39 rows=796 width=16) (actual time=5449.853..5449.857 rows=6 loops=3)
         Sort Key: x.ts_updated DESC, x.content_id
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=3763.88..2273207.05 rows=796 width=16) (actual time=758.171..5449.771 rows=6 loops=3)
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=3763.31..2266731.60 rows=804 width=24) (actual time=757.420..5448.394 rows=6 loops=3)
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=3762.75..2123318.42 rows=12185 width=16) (actual time=154.876..5225.047 rows=1174 loops=3)
                           ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on program_title pt  (cost=3762.18..915178.93 rows=148719 width=8) (actual time=127.751..1700.129 rows=35052 loops=3)
                                 Recheck Cond: (title ~~* '%game%'::text)
                                 Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 538241
                                 Heap Blocks: exact=21476 lossy=13224
                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on title_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..3672.95 rows=356926 width=0) (actual time=114.381..114.382 rows=106514 loops=1)
                                       Index Cond: (title ~~* '%game%'::text)
                           ->  Index Scan using content_pkey on content c  (cost=0.57..8.12 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.100..0.100 rows=0 loops=105155)
                                 Index Cond: (content_id = pt.content_id)
                                 Filter: (type = 3)
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                     ->  Index Scan using content_map_content_id_idx on content_map cm  (cost=0.57..11.76 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.189..0.189 rows=0 loops=3522)
                           Index Cond: (content_id = c.content_id)
                           Filter: (service_id = 81)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 1
               ->  Index Scan using program_pkey on program x  (cost=0.56..8.05 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.213..0.213 rows=1 loops=19)
                     Index Cond: (content_id = c.content_id)
                     Filter: (rating_tags = '{}'::text[])
 Planning time: 5.220 ms
 Execution time: 5465.618 ms
```

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT x.content_id
 FROM program AS x
 JOIN content AS c ON c.content_id=x.content_id  
 JOIN content_map AS cm ON cm.content_id=x.content_id 
 WHERE x.rating_tags='{}' AND c.type= 3 AND cm.service_id= 81 
 ORDER BY x.ts_updated DESC,x.content_id;


 Gather Merge  (cost=6297683.32..6313303.04 rows=133874 width=16) (actual time=21371.202..21381.545 rows=2962 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Sort  (cost=6296683.29..6296850.64 rows=66937 width=16) (actual time=21332.203..21332.283 rows=987 loops=3)
         Sort Key: x.ts_updated DESC, x.content_id
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 100kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2315952.94..6291318.12 rows=66937 width=16) (actual time=18900.715..21331.587 rows=987 loops=3)
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=2315952.38..5085939.17 rows=152985 width=16) (actual time=18899.812..21258.308 rows=987 loops=3)
                     Hash Cond: (cm.content_id = c.content_id)
                     ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on content_map cm  (cost=142330.28..2871084.70 rows=1867189 width=8) (actual time=2921.231..4853.078 rows=1446080 loops=3)
                           Recheck Cond: (service_id = 81)
                           Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 4864262
                           Heap Blocks: exact=21074 lossy=81728
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on content_map_service_idx  (cost=0.00..141209.96 rows=4481253 width=0) (actual time=2913.362..2913.364 rows=4338252 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: (service_id = 81)
                     ->  Hash  (cost=2082303.32..2082303.32 rows=5566062 width=8) (actual time=15626.439..15626.441 rows=5820430 loops=3)
                           Buckets: 131072  Batches: 128  Memory Usage: 2798kB
                           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on content c  (cost=342229.55..2082303.32 rows=5566062 width=8) (actual time=9786.370..14725.485 rows=5820430 loops=3)
                                 Recheck Cond: (type = 3)
                                 Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 18108078
                                 Heap Blocks: exact=58335 lossy=267266
                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on metadata_content_type_idx  (cost=0.00..340838.03 rows=5566062 width=0) (actual time=9763.856..9763.856 rows=5820514 loops=3)
                                       Index Cond: (type = 3)
               ->  Index Scan using program_pkey on program x  (cost=0.56..7.88 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.073..0.073 rows=1 loops=2962)
                     Index Cond: (content_id = c.content_id)
                     Filter: (rating_tags = '{}'::text[])
 Planning time: 1.622 ms
 Execution time: 21382.836 ms
```

Comment: FWIW, Partitioning is not a tool for improving querying performance (DQL queries, that is). It's a linear segregation of the data as opposed to indexing which is an exponential segregation of the data, meaning with the proper key used in both cases, indexing will be significantly faster. Whatever partition key you planned to use to segregate the data should likely be part of your index instead. I'd have to review your queries and query plans more closely to suggest a proper index, but someone else more versed in PostgreSQL might beat me to the punch.

Comment: Ok, that's helpful to get a nudge in the right direction. I'll look into index improvements we can make.